# In Eclipse, how do I run a JUnit test case multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a unit test that fails sometimes and debugging it is a pain because I don't know why it sometimes fails.

Is there a way inside Eclipse that I can run a JUnit test 5 times or 50 times or something?

Thanks.

Comment: what is that u're trying to test?

Comment: IMHO unit tests failing 'sometimes' are useless.

Comment: Mine too. That's why I want to fix it. I need to run it multiple times so I can diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Thom: Apologies, misunderstood your question.

Comment: You can also use the annotation @Repeat(5) to run five times

Comment: That annotation comes from Spring if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Thom Have a look at my answer. BTW: why don't you accept the most useful answer you got?

Comment: Because none of them are the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: @Thom I didn't receive the notification for your answer, you should put a @ with my username next time. Well, you got some different solutions. The real answer would be: with eclipse this isn't possible out of the box actually. Have you found a better solution? Maybe you can add it as answer as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way of running the same junit test over and over?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492856/easy-way-of-running-the-same-junit-test-over-and-over)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a test decorator for this. See Junit API at 
http://junit.org/apidocs/junit/extensions/RepeatedTest.html

for example

```
@Test  
@Repeat(10)  
public void FailRandomlyNeedToKnowWhy() {  
    ....
}
```

Comment: The `RepeatedTest` decorator comes from JUnit while your code example contains a Spring annotation, isn't it?

Answer (score 15):

I just found the following solution which doesn't require any additional depedency (Spring is required for one of the answers you got).

Run your test with the `Parameterized` runner:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
```

Then add the following method to provide a number of empty parameters equals to the number of times you want to run the test:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static List<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[10][0]);
}
```

This way you don't even have to write a loop. IntelliJ and eclipse also group the results of every iteration together.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried something like this?

```
@Test
public void runMultipleTests() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myTestMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh. There's a thought. I might try that if I get desperate.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired on [this solution](https://gist.github.com/fappel/8bcb2aea4b39ff9cfb6e):

Use @Repeat annotation like this:

```java
public class MyTestClass {

    @Rule
    public RepeatRule repeatRule = new RepeatRule();

    @Test
    @Repeat(10)
    public void testMyCode() {
        //your test code goes here
    }
}
```

You'll only need these two classes:

Repeat.java:

```java
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Target({ METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
public @interface Repeat {
    int value() default 1;
}
```

RepeatRule.java:

```java
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class RepeatRule implements TestRule {

    private static class RepeatStatement extends Statement {
        private final Statement statement;
        private final int repeat;    

        public RepeatStatement(Statement statement, int repeat) {
            this.statement = statement;
            this.repeat = repeat;
        }

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
                statement.evaluate();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement statement, Description description) {
        Statement result = statement;
        Repeat repeat = description.getAnnotation(Repeat.class);
        if (repeat != null) {
            int times = repeat.value();
            result = new RepeatStatement(statement, times);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**2016-10-25 Edit:**
In order to use this solution when using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`, update to [Powermock 1.6.5](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/releases/tag/powermock-1.6.5) (*which includes [this patch](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/427)*).

Comment: It took me a bit to verify that it was rerunning, but I noticed that the time increased from 6 seconds to 2 minutes for 1 vs 1000 runs. However, it does not actually create a new run for each, which resulted in me removing a timeout rule I had.